# Grid.Column-Binding: Different behaviour on WPF and Windows Store App

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, mvvm

I want to place items on a grid.columns dependent on a "ColumnIndex"-value of that item.
Now I have the exact same code on both WPF and a Windows 8.1 Store App. I use XAML/C# and the MVVM-Light toolkit. I want to use that concept for creating a calendar where the entries on that can vary dependent on how many entries are taking place in same timespans.

Here is the code:

```
  var ItemsList = new ObservableCollection<object>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        {
            ItemsList.Add(new
            {
                Index = i,
                Margin = new Thickness(0, 60 * i, 0, 0),
                ColumnIndex = ColumnIndex(i),
            });
        }

        this.DataContext = ItemsList;
    }

    private int ColumnIndex(int i)
    {
        //Purpose: Place every third item the third column
        if (i % 3 == 0) return 2;
        return 0;
    }
```

And the corresponding XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <ItemsControl Grid.Column="1"
              ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                </Grid>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <!-- Those Bindings work fine -->
                <Grid Height="20"
            Width="80"
            Margin="{Binding Margin}">
                    <Grid.Background>
                        <SolidColorBrush Color="Orange" />
                    </Grid.Background>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="FrameworkElement">
                <!-- (Windows App version: This line only works with static numbers (0,1,2) and 
            then changes the Column of all Elements -->
                <Setter Property="Grid.Column"
              Value="{Binding ColumnIndex}" />
            </Style>
        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

The results are below:

WPF:

[image: WPF]

Windows App:

[image: Windows App]

The Windows-App does not do what it is supposed to do. But why is that? I really need this feature and it drives me nuts that I can't get it done...

Thank you very much for your help!
FunkyPeanut

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that WinRT does not support Setter-Bindings without doing a little workaround. I made this work on The Windows-App-Version by overrinding the ItemsControl and creating my own:

```
public class MyItemsControl : ItemsControl
{
    protected override void PrepareContainerForItemOverride(DependencyObject element, object item)
    {
        base.PrepareContainerForItemOverride(element, item);
        FrameworkElement source = element as FrameworkElement;
        source.SetBinding(Grid.ColumnProperty, new Binding { Path = new PropertyPath("ColumnIndex") });
    }
}
```

By doing that I can also remove the `<ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle/>`.

So happy duh!

Credits to: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5aae0981-34e8-47d8-b6a2-bba47ace327b/problem-in-winrt-items-control-with-itemspaneltemplate-as-canvas?forum=winappswithcsharp

Thank you anyways :)